# Installing SQL server express 2008 SP1 on Windows 7

Tags: localhost, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm installing (well trying to) SQL server express 2008 SP1 on Windows 7

This is not working for me.

I started by installing VS2010 B2, it installed SQL 2008 Express.

I went into the 'SQL Server Configuration Manager' and enabled the TCPIP protocol and Named Pipes under 'SQL Server Network Configuration' for the SQLExpress instance.

I then installed SSMS. When I try to connect to localhost, I get:

[image]

I am at wit's end here.
I'm sure this is a duplicate.
I'm on Windows 7 64-bit and I'm installing 64-bit SQL versions when they are available.

Comment: Have you (re)started SQL Server services ? Try rebooting Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you're giving the full server instance name. For me it was \SQLEXPRESS. I got the same error until I added the computer name.

Comment: Agreed. It should be **computer_name\SQLEXPRESS**, or **localhost\SQLEXPRESS** if connecting to the same computer as SQL Server is installed on.